# How can I set UIDatePicker to display dates for today and onward?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker

Is there a way to set the date of the UIDatePicker to be dynamic? How can I set the `Minumum Date` to be the current date?

[image: Image Of Date Picker]

Comment: UIDatePicker has minimum and maximum date setters. You can use:
```datePicker.minimumDate = Date()``` for start date(Today or Now) and ```datePicker.maximumDate = someDate``` for end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple Datepickerview with minimum date set to Today

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

// Create a DatePicker
     let datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

     // Posiiton date picket within a view
     datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)

     // Set some of UIDatePicker properties
    datePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.minimumDate = Date()

     self.view.addSubview(datePicker)


}
```

}

[image: result]

Comment: It's giving me an error ('UIDatePicker?' is not convertible to 'Date?')

Comment: set datePickerMode = .date also

Comment: `Date.minimumDate = Date()`

Comment: The only code for it is
`@IBOutlet weak var Date: UIDatePicker!`
and
`Date.minimumDate = Date()` and `Date.datePickerMode = .date`

Comment: try change the variable name of DatePicker, Date to another one (EX:- myDatePicker)

Comment: Wait I think you're answering the wrong question, I wanted the minimum date to be the current date

Comment: In my code I set the minimum date to current date. you can try my code

Comment: Turns out `Date` was invalid for a name. Thanks a lot anyway!